# Finish CSS3 animation when document loaded

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following infinite animation running from the start that acts as a page loader:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinX {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

And on window load i m running the following JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var _logo_x = document.getElementById("logo-x");
    _logo_x.addEventListener("animationiteration", introLogo(_logo_x), false);
}
function introLogo(_ele)
{
  _ele.removeClass('rotate');
}
```

The problem that i m facing is that it cuts the current iteration instead of waiting for it.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58DLd/1/)

Comment: Try adding a transition to the element.

Comment: @minitech as in the rotate effect to the element instead of the class ?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a `play state` with JS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

Comment: @Paulie_D the animation is infinite, how is this relevant to detecting when the window is loaded and finish the last iteration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_logo_x.addEventListener("animationiteration", introLogo(_logo_x), false);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
introLogo(_logo_x);
_logo_x.addEventListener("animationiteration", undefined, false);
```

You want:

```
_logo_x.addEventListener("animationiteration", function() {introLogo(_logo_x)}, false);
```

Comment: It no longer calls introLogo(); I m guessing animationiteration isn't working, i tried the vendor prefix variants and transitionend still nothing.

Comment: @PatsyIssa i modified your fiddle as stated in this answer, and it DO work

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano care to share said modified fiddle.

Comment: @bjb568 turns out it was the "webkitAnimationIteration" syntax, cheers.

Comment: @Patsy Oh. :P Those dern vendor prefixes. So unhelpful, yet so annoying.